# How to test class method using rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

Hi i am working on RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5.0. I have a model forgot_password where a class method is defined to create a record as follows:-

```
forgot_password.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ForgotPassword < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :create_token

  def self.create_record
    self.create!(expiry: Time.zone.now +
                 ENV['VALIDITY_PERIOD'].to_i.hours)
  end

  private

  def create_token
    self.token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
  end
end
```

I want to write unit testing for it using stub or factory_girl gem.

```
spec/models/forgot_password_spec.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

describe ForgotPassword do
  let(:forgot_password) do
    described_class.new()
  end

  describe 'create_record' do
    context 'with forgot_password class' do
      subject { forgot_password.create_record.class }

      it { is_expected.to eq ForgotPassword }
    end
  end
end
```

But its throwing error `undefined method create_record for #<ForgotPassword:0x000000000622bc98>` Please help me how can i test my model. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stop instantiating an instance of the described class?

Comment: sorry i didnot get your point

Comment: how can i test my model where i have a class method and before_create callback?

Answer (score 1):

What you have written is  a factory method (a class method that returns an instance) you should call it and write expectations about the instance returned:

```
describe ForgotPassword do
  describe ".create_record" do
    subject { described_class.create_record! }
    it { is_expected.to be_an_instance_of(described_class) }
    it "sets the expiry time to a time in the future" do
      expect(subject.expiry > Time.now).to be_truthy
    end
  end
end
```

However if what you really are looking to do is set a computed default value then there is a much less clunky way:

```
class ForgotPassword < ApplicationRecord
  after_initialize :set_expiry!

  private

  def set_expiry!
    self.expiry(expiry: Time.zone.now).advance(hours: ENV['VALIDITY_PERIOD'].to_i)
  end
end
```

Or with Rails 5:

```
class ForgotPassword < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :expiry, :datetime, 
    ->{ Time.zone.now.advance(hours: ENV['VALIDITY_PERIOD'].to_i) }
end
```

You can test it by:

```
describe ForgotPassword do
  let(:forgot_password){ described_class.new }
  it "has a default expiry" do
    expect(forgot_password.expiry > Time.now).to be_truthy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test against `described_class` directly:
    require 'rails_helper'

```
describe ForgotPassword do
  context 'with forgot_password class' do
    subject { described_class }

    it { is_expected.to eq ForgotPassword }
  end
end
```